# Efficient moving window statistics for matrix and/or spatial data (neighborhood statistics) in R

Tags: r, spatial, moving-average

I'm using the raster and related packages in R to do a bit of remote sensing work. For a number of the functions I'm writing, I'd love to rapidly compute neighborhood / moving window statistics. Unfortunately, any R implementations I or others write are very, very slow.

I know that the caTools package offers this functionality written in C for vectors / time series, which yields a 10X+ time savings. Is anyone familiar with a similar package or function that provides this functionality for matrices and spatial data?

Quick example:

```
# Generate a raster with random values
r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100)
values(r) <- rbinom(dim(r)[1] * dim(r)[2], 1, 0.1)

# Now generate a raster highlighting the original values plus immediate neighbors
# (By default ngb yields a queen-esque weighting system)
r.neighbor <- focal(r, ngb=3, fun=max)

# system.time() of the above function for a 100x100 raster takes 0.8 seconds on my laptop
# and takes over 15 seconds for a 1000x1000 raster
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this faster and for much larger rasters.

Much thanks,
Nick

Ps. There's some interesting discussion of the massive speed differences across R functions for doing moving window operations on vectors here: http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/10/5161.html

Comment: A sample case would be useful. There are multiple ways to do that, going from using `embed()` to more specific packages. But you'll have to give us a bit more detail, as the optimal method depends pretty much on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Surprised Dirk hasn't chimed in here with Rcpp

Comment: More details are welcome.  It's not quite clear, though, why you're interested in a moving average for your case.  Do you perhaps mean to do some kind of either (1) smoothing of spatial data or (2) density estimation (or isocontours)?

Comment: Fair enough. Sorry that wasn't clear -- updated above with a few additional details of what I'm trying to do.